# Decide between struct and class to represent a hexahedron in a scenario where there will be millions of them in memory

Tags: c#, .net, performance, garbage-collection

I have a pretty non trivial design problem on .net 4.5. I have a grid that is supposed to have millions of hexahedrons. Each hexahedron has 8 points and 6 quadrilateral faces. Each quadrilateral face may be planar or curved. If it is planar, it is represented by a (class|struct) called Plane, that has 4 doubles for the plane equation and has the 4 vertices of the quadrilateral. If the face is Curved, it is represented by a single point and a 3x3 matrix.

The main concern here is performance, garbage collection, assuming a memory limit of 2gb for any array of blocks. The question is: we have Block, Point, Face, Plane, Curve, Matrix3x3. Which of them should be class and which of them should be struct?

Comment: It sounds to me like there is a lot of potential redundancy in your data. If you have the four vertices then you don't need the data for the plane equation as well; you can work it out as needed from any three of the four vertices. If you have two adjoining planar faces then two of the vertices among the eight will be the same. Rather than worrying about structs or classes right now I would start by making everything smaller if you're so concerned about memory.

Comment: You may find [Peformance Quiz #11](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2006/08/31/performance-quiz-11-ten-questions-on-value-based-programming.aspx) to be of interest.

Comment: You can also follow this simple rule. If two instances with the same data created at two different places in your code represent the same information, then it should probably be a struct. Otherwise it is class.

For example, if I create two instances of a DateTime with the same date/time/zone they represent only one possible date. DateTime should be a struct.

If I create two instances of Client, both initialized with John Smith, there is still a very high possibility that they represent two different individuals. Then Client should be a class.

Comment: @JohannBlais Why? Two structs with the similar data will be two different objects in memory - the same would happen for two classes. I  believe you're assuming that value types are interned. Unless I misunderstood your comment.

Comment: Eric, ineed to store theplane equatipn because it needs to be reused thousands of times for intersection algorithms. I cannot just recalculate every time. The same for the curve.

Comment: Then you have already decided that time is more important to you than memory.

Comment: More generally, your question is "which of these two different techniques meets my performance goals?"  How on earth should we know?  **Try it both ways and measure to see if either way meets your goals**. If neither meets your goals then you have a bigger problem to solve; if both meet your goals then make a choice based on some other criterion. If one meets your goal and the other doesn't then you know the answer to your question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because no one but the original poster knows whether a particular technique will or will not meet their performance goal on their target hardware.

Comment: actually i am expecting some guidance here. this is  a forum for dicussion, and i am proposing a discussion. performance is a main concern, but memory is not infinite.

Comment: @TapiocaCom Actually, this is a Q&A site and discussions tend to be closed as "Primarily opinion based" ;)

Comment: You have an incorrect idea of what StackOverflow is. It is explicitly documented as **not a discussion forum** and solicitations for discussion are **specifically unwanted**. When you have a *specific question* that can be *answered* come on back and people will be happy to help you.

Answer (score 2):

(Ignoring P/Invoke aspects, which is a different matter)

As a very general rule of thumb, you should only make types with small amounts of data (say 32 bytes) into structs.

Note that structs should ideally be immutable.

In terms of speed: It depends what you're doing, so you would have to perform some timings to really tell. However, it's likely that when you are passing items to a method it will be quicker to pass a reference type rather than a struct type when the struct size is greater than the reference size (which will be 32 bits for 32 bit code and 64 bits for 64 bit code).

One very important thing to bear in mind when creating arrays or List: For value types, the size of the value in bytes times the number of elements is the total contiguous size of the underlying array.

For reference types, the total size is the size of a reference (32 bits or 64 bits) times the size of the array.

Since the maximum size of an array is 2^31 bytes, this can be important if the size of the value type exceeds the size of a reference.

Comment: great point here. if a block is a class, then i can use an array of more blocks because the array is, in fact, storing references to the blocks. But, millions of reference types will cause a painful time on the garbage collector?

Comment: @TapiocaCom Yes, a lot of reference types can make things slower, but sometimes it's less than you think. The only real way to know is to instrument your build and perform some accurate timings using the `Stopwatch` class.

Answer (score 2):

**Updated**

Let's assume we have a `Plane` type with 4 doubles on 64bit system, and that we have 1 million `Plane`s.

- If `SPlane` is a struct, then it would occupy 4*8 = 32 bytes
- If `CPlane` is a class, then it will occupy 4*8 bytes (fields) + 16 bytes (header) = 48 bytes. And don't forget about the 8 bytes for each reference pointing to each instance.

Let's consider the pros and cons of using a struct, instead of a class.

**Pros**

- GC Performance - there are less references to keep track of. The GC will treat an array of `SPlane` an one object. An array of `CPlane` would have to be treated as 1 million + 1 objects.
- Memory space - an array of `SPlane` will occupy 32 million bytes in memory. An array of `CPlane` will occupy 8 million bytes (array of contiguous references) + 48 million bytes (individual instances). Thats 32 million bytes vs 56 million bytes.

**Cons**

- Performance degradation due to copying

  - "resizing"/"expanding" an array of struct planes would copy 32 million bytes, whereas if we were using classes, it would copy the references only (8 million bytes)
  - likewise, things like passing a `SPlane` as an argument to a method, returning an `SPlace` or assigning a variable to another variable, will copy 32 bytes, whereas passing `CPlane` will copy just the reference.
- Usual caveats of using value types.

  - no inheritance (doesn't seem to matter to you anyway)
  - acidental boxing (implicit casting to object or interface, calling `GetType` or non-overriden `ToString`). This one can be mitigated by being careful.
  - no canonical form (no explicit parameterless constructor - you can't restrain the default value of a value type field). E.g., unassigned fields and arrays would, by default, be filled with persons of 0 height - considering `struct Person {int height;}`.
  - no circular dependencies. A struct `Person` cannot contain fields of type `Person`, as that would lead to an infinite memory layout.

Since we don't know your exact use cases, you'll have to make the decision.

Like Matthew Watson suggested, you should measure the performance of both approaches and compare.

Comment: Your first statement doesn't follow logically. Suppose you have a million integers on the heap. A million integers on the heap in the form of an `int[]` takes 4 million bytes and the garbage collector has a network of a single object to check to see if it is alive. A million `class C { int x; }` objects takes 12 million bytes and the GC has a million objects in the network to independently check for aliveness. Those are both *enormous* performance costs!

Comment: @EricLippert I don't think it's fair comparing an `int[]` to an array of `class C{int x;}`. I think we should be comparing a `C[]` to a `S[]`, where `struct S{int x;}`. But nevertheless, you make a great point! A `S[]` would be laid out sequentially in memory and GC would treat this as a network of a single object, whereas a `C[]` would represent a million + 1 objects (1 million `C`s + an array of references laid out sequentially). Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: @EricLippert Also, and this might be a silly question, a single `S` would occupy the same space a single `C`, correct?

Comment: You are understanding it correctly; whether the int is "naked" or wrapped in a struct is not really relevant to its size or layout.

Comment: A single S and a single C are different in size; being a reference type is expensive! Every instance of a reference type in the CLR has 8 extra bytes (or 16, on 64 bit CLR). See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163791.aspx for details.  A struct might have extra memory for padding but has no extra memory for the header because (1) the type of the struct is known from the type of its storage location so there's no need for a type handle, and (2) structs aren't monitors, so there's no need for a sync block.

Comment: A struct can be passed by reference if we use the ref keywotd. Therefore, i think passaing parameters is not a real problem.

Comment: @EricLippert Thanks for the input, I wasn't aware of the differences in the memory layout of structs and classes. Great info ;)

Comment: @TapiocaCom I've updated my answer, hope it helps you make an informed decision.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose one wants to hold one million 3d points, and allow the following operations:

- `double GetX(int index)` // And likewise GetY and GetZ
- `double SetX(int index, double value)` // And likewise SetY and SetZ
- `double SetXYZ(int index, double x, double y, double z)`
- `void CopyCoord(int src, int dest)`

If one uses a mutable structure type:

```
struct Point3dStruct { public double X,Y,Z; }
Point3dStruct[] array;
```

the operations would become:

```
void init()
{
  array = new Point3dStruct[1000000];
}

double GetX(int index)
{ return array[index].X; }

double SetX(int index, double value)
{ array[index].X = value; }

double SetXYZ(int index, double x, double y, double z)
{ array[index].X = x; array[index].Y = y; array[index].Y = z; }

void CopyCoord(int src, int dest)
{ array[dest] = array[src]; }
```

All operations would be reasonably efficient; 24,000,000 bytes would be required to hold 1,000,000 points, regardless of whether some or all of them were the same or different.

Using a so-called "immutable" struct would require changing the `SetX` and `SetXYZ` methods:

```
double SetX(int index, double value)
{
  Point3dStruct temp = array[index];
  array[index] = new Point3dStruct(value, temp.Y, temp.Z);
}

double SetXYZ(int index, double x, double y, double z)
{
  array[index] = new Point3dStruct(x, y, z);
}
```

Performance for `SetX` would be much inferior to that of a simple exposed-field struct; no method would perform better than the exposed-field-struct equivalent.  Memory requirements would not be affected by whether the struct was mutable or not.

A mutable class would require code much like a mutable struct except for the `init` and `CopyCoord` methods.

```
void init()
{
  array = new Point3dClass[1000000];
  for (int i=0; i<1000000; i++)
    array[i] = new Point3dClass();
}

void CopyCoord(int src, int dest)
{
   array[dest].X = array[src].X;
   array[dest].Y = array[src].Y;
   array[dest].Z = array[src].Z;
}
```

Note that accidentally writing `array[dest] = array[src]` would not copy the values, but would instead totally break the code!  Memory usage would require an extra 16 or 32 bytes per element on 32-bit or 64-bit machines (i.e. 16,000,000 or 32,000,000 bytes) regardless of whether all points held the same or different values.

Use of an immutable class would require code similar to an immutable struct, except for the `init` method:

```
void init()
{
  array = new Point3dClass[1000000];
  var zero = new Point3dClass(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  for (int i=0; i<1000000; i++)
    array[i] = zero;
}
```

Initial memory usage would only be about 4,000,000 or 8,000,000 bytes (on 32- or 64-bit machines, respectively), but every *separately-created* instance of `Point3dClass` would add another 12 or 24 bytes.  If the array holds references to 1,000,000 different instances of `Point3dClass`, those would total up to another 12,000,000 or 24,000,000 bytes.

If code will be using methods analogous to `CopyCoord` more often than it will be using methods analogous to `SetX`, then an immutable class can be a big win.  If it will be using `SetX` a lot, an exposed-field mutable struct will offer the best performance.  Mutable class types may play nicer than mutable structs when stored in collections *other than arrays*, but they have a substantial performance overhead and must be used with extreme care.  The only advantage of immutable structs is that code which is written for an immutable struct can often be changed easily to use an immutable class instead.