# Could the use of nullable structs improve performance?

Tags: c#, performance, struct, garbage-collection

I was thinking the following:

Since, structs can improve GC performance and `Nullable<T>` is a  struct itself, would it be better in terms of performance (GC performance or overall) to use a nullable struct instead of a class?

Has anyone experience on this?

**EDIT:**

E.g.: I was thinking more about creating an options class/struct for a method call: `ConvertToPdf(..., MyType options)`. So, not extra huge structs with many methods or anything like that.

Comment: Do you have an actual performance problem that you can demonstrate that a nullable struct produces an improvement for? If not, you should probably stick to "use a struct/value type when the thing is defined by its value"

Comment: No, this is just an enquiry of mine. It just popped up on my mind.

Comment: The *possibility* of not being stored on the heap is not the only difference between a value type and a reference type. There are *many* other things you have to consider. I've listed quite a few here: [Decide between struct and class...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22148649)

Comment: You don't write highly performant code by micro-analysing each part of your programming language, identify the "best" option for each part, and then writing all code according to those options. You write performant code by writing *clear*, readable code and setting actual performance goals. Then, you check whether your code meets your goals. If it does, great, you're done. If it doesn't, then you start analyzing the code as a whole and identifying where the actual bottlenecks are and how to fix them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

`structs`.. being the basis for value types, should remain small. Classes don't generally remain small, and so by substituting all uses of a class for a `struct`.. you will be creating in fact slower runtime speeds.. since value types are copied in their entirety.

Comment: You are right. But if we suppose that they are not huge structs and that they are not copied much? E.g. I was thinking about creating an options class/struct for a method call: `ConvertToPdf(....., MyType options)`

Comment: @user2173353 A type that is small and is instantiated very often *may* be a good candidate for a value type. But 1) don't worry about that unless performance is *really* critical and 2), if you decide to give it a try, measure it to see if there's any actual performance gains!!

Comment: Honestly, if you're that worried about speed, then the guideline is generally "structs should be smaller than 16 bytes in size". This is because that is basically the cut-ff point where people generally agree that it would actually be faster for a reference type to have higher throughput.. since they are just a reference (4/8 bytes - depending on platform). No doubt people have measured this (I have never bothered.. but makes perfect sense to me).

Answer (score 1):

A structure is semantically equivalent to a bunch of variables stuck together with duct tape.  If one were to create a structure

```
public struct MaybeValid<T>
{
  public T Value;
  public bool IsValid;
}
```

then the `Value` field of a variable of a `MaybeValid<T>` could be worked with just as efficiently as a variable of type `T`.  The Framework's `Nullable<T>` isn't defined that way, however.  Consequently, it's often necessary to copy the `Value` of a `Nullable<T>` to some other variable before anything can be done with it.  The extra layers of copying required when using `Nullable<T>` mean that code using it will generally be nowhere near as efficient as code using other types could be.

Answer (score 0):

Premature optomisation! - given that possible as you don't get boxing directly as you would wrapping it in a class you can make nullable. Assuming of course that use of a struct is appropriate - you do tend to see a lot of classes with very few members, these could be a target. But you dont want to optomize like this until you know you need to because you are only a mortal.