# Should I use struct instead of class to put items int dictionary

Tags: c#, class, dictionary, struct, value-type

I've a custom Entity class (see code below). The objects of this class get populated into a Dictionary collection `Dictionary<string, Dictionary <uint,Entity>> dt` .  Someone ask me to use Struct instead of Class, since value types won't get copied into heap. Well, I think in this case Class seems better choice since Dictionary will then only contains reference to the objects of type Entity. Entity type in this case represents a row in a csv file. So for every row there will be a Entity type object. The encapsulated Dictionary within Entity type contains key,value pair representing column,value for a row in a csv file.

But I want to make sure I didn't miss anything obvious so thought better to ask.

```
 public class Entity
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> dtValues = new Dictionary<string,string>(); //contains values    from CSV file.
        public Dictionary<string, string> Values
        {
          get { return dtValues; }
          set { dtValues = value; }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> Someone ask me to use Struct instead of Class, since value types won't get copied into heap.

That person is dead wrong. Simply put: the dictionary itself is on the heap, so its contents will also be on the heap.

If you're not sure whether your should use a reference type or a value type, then you should research the pros and cons of both (I listed a few [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22148649/857807)). But you should *probably* use a reference type.

Remember: premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: Well, it depends on what that person meant. A value type does not create additional objects on the heap, though it itself may be on the heap, for the very reason you cited.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen What do you mean by "additional objects on the heap"?

Comment: A value type may live on the heap, but only as the value type. If you use a reference, the reference may live on the heap but the object it refers to will be an additional object.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen You mean an array of 100 value types would allocate 1 object on the heap, whereas an array of 100 reference types would allocate 101 objects on the heap? That's very true (I actually have that listed as one of the pros), but I don't think the sentence the OP quoted can be interpreted that way. I don't think that's what he meant.

Comment: No, probably not, but as I said in comments on both answers here, heavy-handed saying either scenario is good or bad is not entirely correct, but I completely agree. *Most likely*, reference types is what is required here. I also note that he calls the type in question an "Entity" so I am assuming there's a database entity in play here, those are usually not small enough that a value type is a good idea.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen that was my exact reasoning :) I didn't say flat out "don't use it" or "use it". I think the OP should do more research on the subject before deciding. One thing's certain, we can't make that decision for him (based on the given context).

Comment: There's also the fact that there are numerous answers by members of the C# team that amount to 'don't trust some things to be on the stack and others on the heap'

Answer (score 1):

Using a Dictionary of Structs is always a really bad idea because when you enumerate it or do anything with it's values you will be copying the data over and over, so using classes is the right way, in this manner only references are moved.

Comment: But references may or may not be the same size as the struct, and even copying the structs may perform better than having the objects and the GC pressure. The *correct* message to convey is that it depends on what the types contain, and how you use them, and thus the only way to make performance suggestions here is to measure. Your answer is equally bad in the general sense as the one you claim is bad.

Comment: Are you using a struct to use less than 4 bytes or 8 bytes (x86 vs x64)?? really?? the only thing I can think about is a struct of four booleans...

Comment: If you want to have a type safe value that means something other than an Int32, but is internally stored as an Int32, then yes, you can have that, but also note that in my experience, small structs may have beneficial performance characteristics, even if they are slightly larger than a reference. It depends on how you use them.

Comment: In the case of some uses (vertex for directx/opengl come to my mind really fast), yes, I agree, sometimes structs get benefits, but using them on dictionaries does not get any benefits but the memory copy detriment.

Comment: I agree with @LasseV.Karlsen, your advice is just as bad. There may be situations where the benefits of using a value type weigh more than the overhead of all those copies.

Comment: "does not get any benefits" There *are* other benefits. Assuming a 64bit system, a dictionary of 1 million structs, where each struct has an int field, would occupy 1m * 4B = 4 MB (plus a few more bytes for the dict's internal state). The same dictionary of reference types would occupy 1m * 20 bytes (the objects) + 1m * 8 bytes (the references) = 28 MB. If memory space were more important than performance, then value types would be the way to go.

Comment: Actually, in the scenario I described above, using value types would not only improve memory usage, it *might* also improve performance, as the GC would have 1 million less references to keep track of.

Comment: Ok, that's just nonsense, "where each struct has an int field", so you are doing structs to save an int?? really?? why don't you just store that int?? In the case of "two ints" it starts to become closer, and also, you are playing with pointer and data size, if you execute that in an x86 machine it will be 4 bytes per pointer. If you are doing things like those, then use the dictionary to store array indexes and store your data into an array.

Comment: There is no problem with a `Dictionary<,>` of structs, for example a `Dictionary<int, DateTime>` where `int` is a pre-defined value type, and `DateTime` is a "user-defined" (defined in `mscorlib.dll`) value type. Also note that `KeyValuePair<,>` is a value type.

Comment: *"so you are doing structs to save an int?? really?? why don't you just store that int??"* Because sometimes it is beneficial because although all your underlying type is just a single simple data type it may be beneficial to represent that data type [in a special way](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/timespan.cs#83e476c1ae112117#references).

Comment: @Scott, that's a long, not an int ^_^, but yes, nice catch, that case is one where you will use a struct with only one member.

Answer (score 1):

Types which hold references to mutable objects for the purpose of encapsulating state should generally avoid exposing those objects to outside code.  I don't quite understand what the purpose of your `Entity` type would be, since the only apparent content is a reference to a `Dictionary` [which is, of course, a mutable type].

In general, if one wishes to store things in a collection and is trying to decide between using a class or a struct for the things to be stored, I would suggest the following:

1. If you use a mutable class type for list items or dictionary *values* [not keys], you may edit the information stored in an item without having to involve the collection itself in the process.  Making information contained in an item available to outside code, however, will require either cloning the data item or copying data from it into something else.
2. If you use an immutable class type, or any structure type, for things stored in a collection, editing the information contained in an item will require reading out the item, producing a changed version, and storing it back.  Making information contained in the item available to outside code, however, will be much easier, since one can return it as its own data type.
3. A pattern which is sometimes useful is to define a mutable structure type but then define a wrapper type something like the following:

   ```
   public class ExposedFieldHolder<T>
   {
     public T Value;
     ExposedFieldHolder(T value) { Value = value; }
   }
   ```

If `Value` is a field, rather than a property, and one creates e.g. a `Dictionary<string, ExposedFieldHolder<someStruct>>`, then it will be possible to edit data while it's stored within the dictionary `e.g.`myDict["George"].Value.Age++;`but it will also be possible to give the data associated with an entry to outside code [e.g.`return myDict[name].Value;`].

Having a simple exposed-field structure encapsulated within an `ExposedFieldHolder<T>` can be safer and more convenient than simply using a mutable class (since one can return a holder's entire `Value` without giving outside code access to the holder itself), and also more convenient than using an immutable class or structure (since one can modify list items or dictionary values without having to use a readout-modify-writeback sequence).  It is less space-efficient than simply storing an exposed-field structure directly in the collection.  If one stored an exposed-field struct directly as a dictionary value without using an `ExposedFieldHolder, the above update to George's age would require the three-step process:

```
var temp = myDict["George"];
temp.Age++;
myDict["George"] = temp;
```

but that may still be better than what an immutable class or so-called "immutable" structure would require, e.g.

```
var temp = myDict["George"];
temp = new PersonDat(temp.Name, temp.Age+1, temp.FavoriteColor, temp.AstrologicalSign);
myDict["George"] = temp;
```

Note that if one consistently follows the former pattern when using exposed-field structures, the code will be correct regardless of what fields or properties the structure contains or the order in which they appear.  By contrast, when using the latter pattern one must be very careful to ensure any fields or properties whose value should not be changed get passed to the constructor in the proper sequence.  Some people may like that kind of code; I think it's horrible.

Comment: Entity type in this case represents a row in a csv file. So for every row there will be a Entity type object. The encapsulated Dictionary within Entity type contains key,value pair representing column,value for a row in a csv file.

Comment: @user2177565: Is there any particular reason to use an `Entity` type rather than e.g. an `ImmutableDictionary<string, string>`, perhaps stored in a `Dictionary<string, ImmutableDictionary<string, string>>`?  If you might need to attach some additional information to an entity, an exposed-field struct which includes an `ImmutableDictionary<string,string>` plus other data might be the best approach [possibly wrapped in an `ExposedFieldHolder<T>` as described above, depending upon usage]

Comment: The main reason of using Entity type (besides that it represent a csv row) is that its pushed into another dictionary Dictionary<string, Dictionary <uint,Entity>> dt. The dt key aggregates certain Entitles based on business logic. If I don't use the Entity type then the dt will look like "Dictionary<string, Dictionary <uint,Dictionary<string,string>>>". Also I wasn't aware of ImmutableDictionary type.

Comment: @user2177565: There are advantages and disadvantages to adding a type like `Entity`; they largely boil down to the question of whether it's more useful to allow code to assume that entities will be equivalent if all key-value pairs match, or whether it's better to allow information to be added to entities outside the key-value pairs.  If code is going to assume that an entity set of key-value pairs is equivalent to any other with those same k/v pairs, then it may be better *not* to have `Entity` as a distinct type; if code won't assume that, the type might be useful.

Comment: @user2177565: Boxing only occurs if a value of type `struct` is stored into a storage location *of some other type*.  Adding a `SomeStruct` to a `Dictionary<string, SomeStruct>` would not require boxing since it's being stored as `SomeStruct`, but adding it to a `Dictionary<string, Object>` or a non-generic dictionary would require boxing.

Comment: Yes, you're correct the code did not assume that. So, as it stands if Struct is used for the Entity type would there be boxing/unboxing every time whenever following code pattern is used?  

    `//boxing?
     dt["ko101"].Add(1,entity);

    `//unboxing
     var value =   dt["ko101"].Values[1];

Comment: @user2177565: If entity is a struct, then your indicated code would not have any boxing or unboxing.